# File Handling:What is the use of peek() function in c++?

Tags: c++

As I have so much problem while dealing with the eof of a file, whenever I code with `fstream` and the `eof` appears I have to clear the stream in order to work with that stream. Although I have searched a lot about the `eof` and I got the result that I should start using:

```
fstream file("Filename.txt",ios::in|ios::ate|ios::out);
char str[80];
while(file>>str)
{
    //do the required stuff
}
//clear the stream and reuse it
file.clear();
file.seekp(0);
```

But I have also read about a function called `peek()` which is also used for such purposes but I am a little confused in its working and I am not able to apply it in the code. So if anyone could guide me through this.

And I have also heard about a function called `putback()` what's that??

Edit-1

```
fstream file("Filename.txt",ios::in|ios::ate|ios::out);
char str[80];
while(file>>str)
{
    //do the required stuff
}
//clear the stream and reuse it
file.clear();
file.seekp(0);
//Now do the required writing operation after reading the whole file wherever is required
//I also want to perform writing operations and if this pattern seems most suitable for me
```

Comment: [`std::istream::peek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) and [`std::istream::putback()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback), what's actually unclear from the reference documentation for you? Also you should just change `char str[80];` to `std::string` and may be use `while(getline(file,str))`. There's no need to test for `eof` explicitly.

Comment: Use the code above, it's the right thing to do. Don't use peek or putback until you actually need them.

Comment: @n.m. Well, applied with a `char str[80];` that could lead to unexpected problems, but in general I'm with you, these functions or testing for `eof` isn't necessary, or even wrong.

Comment: Personally, I don't recall ever using it. Hopefully somebody else has.

Comment: That's why i am asking for some better coding pattern which could be applied. And if i use while(getline(file,str)) will it automatically detect the eof??

Comment: i have also heard a pattern while(file.peek()!=eof) is it good to be used but it is not working

Comment: @Harshul I've got a feeling you're asking for a XY-Problem. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Harshul _"will it automatically detect the eof??"_ Yes, it will be detected automatically, `eof` represents a stream state, rather than a particular character value encountered.

Comment: Whenever i create some file handling code i face problems after reaching eof which is really awful so when i asked about this topic many developers told me to use the above mentioned syntax but I have also heard about peek() function. I want that in file handling i should be able to use a stream for how long i want it and not be be interrupted by eof error's. Although I have learnt about clear() function which clears the stream whenever a stream contains failbit but it is a little idiotic

Comment: ok if it will automatically detect the eof then wouldn't the stream get fail bit on reaching eof??

Comment: Can you describe what you ACTUALLY want to do? Given that you do `seekp`, I expect you are writing to the file after that point. So why no just create a new file, instead of writing to the existing one? That would remove the need for `seekp` and `reset` problems and make it easier to understand.

Comment: Lets say I want to create a database file so if I want to add contents to my database then i need to edit that file instead of just creating a new file.I i am creating a code to manage accounts then if i want to add a new account then first i would have to check the whole file that if such account exists  then code should show error that account exists else a new account should be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to write a parser for C or C++ and your code does something like this:

```
 char c = source.get();
 switch(c)
 {
    ... 
    case '<':
        // May be < or <=
        if (source.peek() == '=')
        {
           source.get();
           return less_or_equal;
        }
        // Ok, not <= so:
        return less;
   ...
}
```

[I ignored that it may be part of a template, a shift, or something else like that]

The need for `putback()` is very little when you have `peek()`, but it does allow code that "normally consumes" the character to put it back "if it got it wrong". Say you know that `<=` is more common than `<`, then you could do:

```
 char c = source.get();
 switch(c)
 {
    ... 
    case '<':
        // May be < or <=
        c = source.get();
        if (c == '=')
        {
           source.get();
           return less_or_equal;
        }
        source.putback(c);
        // Ok, not <= so:
        return less;
   ...
}
```

because it only does `putback` on the rare case [as per the assumed statistics above].

One can imagine cases where the common case is to `get` and the rare case is mismatch, e.g. if we want to read a number:

```
  int number = 0;
  do
  {
      char c = input.get();
      if (isdigit(c))
      {
           number *= 10;
           number += c - '0';
      }
      else
      {
           input.putback(c);
      }
while( isdgit(c) );
```

Since, most numbers have more than one digit in them, the more common case is that the first and the subsequent character is a digit, and the unusual case is that we need to call `putback()`. [Of course, reading numbers "properly" will require a bit more stuff...]

Comment: No man you did not understand my problem i just want escape the setting of failbit after reaching eof so that i would not have to everytime clear the stream

Comment: I explained what they are for. They are NOT for "escaping setting the bad bit" in the first place, not their purpose, not what you should do. Don't even try that. That's the wrong solution. Just close the file, open it again for writing.

Comment: Ain't that a little bit idiotic that i would have to close the file and again open it for writing or i can do both with fstream??

Comment: Or if it is so then how to know that where to enter the data as after closing file file will again open from starting?

Comment: Well, you are doing `seekp(0)` which indicates that you are trying to write at the beginning of the file. Since you haven't posted what is in your read-loop, or what you do AFTER the `seekp`, it's really not possible to say what is right and what is wrong, or how to best approach the problem. As with most programming problems, "the devil is in the detail". I'm just suggesting what I would do, which is to open a new file (in fact, I would probably open a file with a different name, and then replace the old file after writing out the new one, but again, it REALLY depends on what you are doing)

Comment: See I have moved file pointer to the starting because i want to reuse the same stream.If i will clear the stream and start using it then it will again read the end of file and will result to the same error situation.So moving the file pointer to the front is just an example that I am going to rewrite in the file as per my writing requirements suppose in my code i get to know where to put write data then i will use seekp(Position,ios::beg); .I just wanted to know that if I will handle the file this way then will it be good, because the comments which appeared in my question were really strange.

Comment: Only if you use `ios::ate`, which of course isn't required.

Comment: But ios::ate is meant for the purpose of editing file so why won't i require that?? I wrote that keeping in mind that i need to edit the data in the stream whenever required (after reading the file if there is a need to make changes)

Comment: Look, are you wanting to "read the whole file, do some stuff to it, and write it out again", in which case I would open an `ifstream` to read it, then close, open an `ofstream` to write it, without `ate` so that the file is truncated. If you want to make changes to the file DURING the read-phase, and put them at the end of the file, then use `ate`.

Comment: if the don't use ios::ate then will the file get edited by just only ios::out and ios::in??

Comment: The default for `ofstream` is `ios::out|ios::trunc`, so the file is cut to 0 length - and doesn't need to be specified as it is the default. Just pass the name, job done.

Comment: No i mean't by a fstream object

Comment: well, obvously, for `fstream`, the `ios::out|ios::trunc` would be required. But unless there is a specific reason to keep the file open during the entire operation (and there MAY be such reasons, but you have not shown what you are doing, so I can only speculate that there are no such reasons), then using an `ifstream` and `ofstream` would be the better solution. Note that `fstream` is basically the `ofstream` anf `ifstream` in one object, so you are not saving anything in creating each separately - maybe a few bytes of "we only need one of these, rather than two", but that's pretty marginal.

Answer (score 2):

> But I have also read about a function called `peek()` which is also used for such purposes

`peek()` was created for a different purpose - it's there to let your program process two characters at a time - essentially emulating `ungetc()` functionality from the portion of the library based on the C standard library.

Using `peek` to see if you are about to hit `eof` is valid, but the approach that you show in the code, i.e. `while(file>>str)`, is more idiomatic to C++ than the one based on `peek`.

> I have also heard about a function called `putback()` what's that?

The `std::putback()` function lets you do the same thing as `ungetc()` does for `FILE*` streams.