# File handling C++:Which is the ideal stream to be used while working with database files?

Tags: c++

I wanted to know about the file handling stream that should be applied while working with database files.I want to create a database file i.e. a file which contains contents and these contents can be edited

Eg-Suppose the file contains data as following

```
Harshul 97  Jack 42  Sergey 69  Bill 96  Mark 92  Will 49
```

It is a database file which contains user's name along with the money in their account (which is stored after account's name).

Now suppose that I want to add a new account to my database for that I would have to first check that if an account already exists because if it exists then I will display error message else i will simply create a new account by appending data into the file.

Now I thought that I would need to edit the data so I should use fstream but while working with fstream I got the problem with the end of file marker which sets good bit to fail bit and stops file i-o operations I got a solution for that i.e. to clear the stream where ever necessary (whenever file pointer hits eof)

Eg-

```
fstream file("Filename.txt",ios::in|ios::ate|ios::out);
char str[80];
while(file>>str)
{
    //do the required stuff
}
//clear the stream and reuse it
file.clear();
file.seekp(0);
```

But this was a little idiotic here so I thought that I should use the peek() function that tells us if the next bit is eof before it but got the result that it is not the right thing to do rather I should open the file again and again [File Handling:What is the use of peek() function in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740689/file-handlingwhat-is-the-use-of-peek-function-in-c/33744157?noredirect=1#comment55272834_33744157)

Whereas I also got the suggestion to use ifstream and ofstream (with no trunc and ate modes) simultaneosly but I wanted to know if I would be able to edit data with it.Suppose I entered details of a new indivisual say "Finch 96" now the ofsteam variable will account for the new entry but for the ifstream object it had read the data of file into its buffer earlier and has no account for our new entry "Finch 96" untill we don't reopen the file in ifstream object

I have searched a lot about this matter but didn't got the result may be I was not able to express my problems properly and now I think that my objective is clear to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text file is nice if you want to be able to edit it *by hand*. If you call it a database, and only want to process it programmatically, you should considere a binary file. At the simplest level, you could have a direct file with fixed size records, that allows you to do in-place record edition. Or if you prefere not to re-invent oval wheels when round ones exist around, you could use a sqlite database which would deal with implementation details for you.

But if you really need a text file, you should read it once in a container of records, and save it all records at a time. A good practice is save to a temp file in same folder and rename it only when everything has successfully be written.

Comment: But if i will read the contents of a file into some data structure(say a structure created to store database records) then it will consume a lots of memory .Isn't it??

Comment: @Harshul: yes it will! That's the reason why real database systems use binary files with direct access. A text file as support for a database implies a memory one because you cannot change the length of a line or add a line in the middle of a text file without rewriting it.

Comment: Although you comment was really helpful too thankyou!!

Comment: So according to you i should write to binary files?? But if i will read all the data from a binary file then it will also consume a lots of memory. Consider a file has 3330 bytes of data then If I began reading the data to some data structure then it will consume 3330 bytes of memory in R.A.M which is  really expensive

Comment: @Harshul: if the file is binary, it can be structured and you will be able to rewrite some records independently. So you are not forced to load everything in memory. But 3 Mbyte memory  is not so expensive nowadays.

Comment: But 3 Mbyte of memory may not be supported by our call stack so I would have to allocate that from heap.One more this is there some allocation limit for heap too?

Comment: One more thing, How to work with a temporary file as told by you in the comment? Is there some way to do that?

Comment: @Harshul: what you are asking for would be rather long for a SO answer... But here are 3 pointers to examples of direct file management: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401176/working-with-direct-access-files-in-c, http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/30080/ and http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/files.htm#showall. Just google for "C++ direct access file" to find more...

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not create  a text file in the first place. Did you consider using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or some real database like [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) or [MongoDb](http://mongodb.org/)?

If you insist on editing programmatically a textual file, the only way is to process every line : either keep all of them in memory, or copy them (except the one you'll change) to some new file.... Which is not very efficient.

You might also be interested in textual [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) formats like [JSON](http://json.org/),it's quite easy to use and very powerful.

Comment: Actually I am really interested on using c++ purely so for that I just  wanted to know that how I should do the file handling by using ifstream ,ofstream or by using fstream and opening the file again and again (using file for a singe operation  at a time i.e. either to read or to write  before closing and reopening it, if i want to  read after writing the file then close it and reopen it) or to allocate stream only once and reusing the same stream for both reading and writing by clearing it and changing position of file pointer.